# Rolling time series with specific (filtered) workdays in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I've got the pandas DataFrame with time-series index and some values. Also the weekday for each date is calculated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4,5,7,4,3,9]},
                   index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130103'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130104'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130105'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130106'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130107'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130108'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130109'),
                            pd.Timestamp('20130110')])
df['wd'] = df.index.weekday
print(df)

Output:
              B  wd
2013-01-01  0.0   1
2013-01-02  1.0   2
2013-01-03  2.0   3
2013-01-04  NaN   4
2013-01-05  4.0   5
2013-01-06  5.0   6
2013-01-07  7.0   0
2013-01-08  4.0   1
2013-01-09  3.0   2
2013-01-10  9.0   3
```

I need to calculate rolling mean values for specific weekday. For example, for (index == '2013-01-09') and (wd == 1) the result must be like np.mean([4,0]) = 2.
Standard pandas rolling function takes the whole window, not filtered.

It can be done by 'manual' index slicing:

```
df['wd'] = df.index.weekday
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['index','wd']).sort_index()
dt = pd.to_datetime('2013-01-09')
rolling_wd = 1
val = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:dt, rolling_wd], :]['B'].mean()

print(val)
2.0
```

But it is very long for big  time series. Is it possible to make it using rolling function on the whole Series?

Comment: `df.groupby('wd')['B'].rolling(2).mean()`?

Comment: Actually I need the value to be calculated on each date for all weekdays. Maybe I need to use 'shift'?

Comment: That should work for each date for all weekdays.

Comment: I think it works only for index  items. But i need it for each item for all weekdays before date